# Сохранение View-элементов, которые были добавлены через код

Tags: java, android, view

Есть такая проблема, все view элементы, которые были добавлены через код (их нет в xml файле) пропадают (что логично), когда я либо переворачиваю экран или скрываю приложение.

Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы все эти view элементы сохранялись и не пропадали?

Comment: [Есть мнение](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html?hl=ru), что для того, чтобы виджеты "пережили" изменение состояния им должен быть присвоен ID, причем ID достаточно присвоить только корневому контейнеру, тогда вложенные в него виджеты тоже будут сохранены при повороте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Первый вариант.**

Вы можете попробовать самостоятельно обработать операцию изменения конфигурации. Для этого в манифест добавьте `android:configChanges`:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

И после этого вы можете обрабатывать изменение конфигурации в классе `onConfigurationChanged` вашего активити (в примере `MyActivity`), например:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange).

**Второй вариант.**

Присвоить идентификатор вашему `View` и создать класс-контейнер для данных, которые вы хотите сохранить. Переопределить метод `onSaveInstanceState()`
у `View` и возвращать в нем экземпляр контейнера. А также переопределить метод
`onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state)` (**при этом важно, что этот метод получает на вход именно Parcelable - собственный `Parcelable`, являющийся наследником `android.view.View.BaseSavedState`, а не `Bundle`!**), получать из контейнера сохраненные данные и применять их к компоненту.

Более подробно и пример кода можете посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542333/how-to-prevent-custom-views-from-losing-state-across-screen-orientation-changes/3542895#3542895).

Comment: провел эксперимент: создал программно вью, присвоил ей ID, сохранил его через бандл, и не могу найти ее через findViewById активити. что я неправильно делаю?

Comment: Не знаю, нужно разбираться... Я присваиваю id программно созданному вью как `myId = View.generateViewId();       customView.setId(myId);` и у меня оно находится через `findViewById`

Answer (score 3):

Исследуйте жизненный цикл Activity. В нем прописаны все случаи (в т.ч. скрытие, смена положения экрана), при которых необходимо создавать и отрисовывать все View's заново.

Answer (score 3):

Для решения таких проблем придумали метод **onResume()**, который вызывается, когда нужно возобновить некую активность с пользователем. Не важно будь то [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) или [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle). Поместите ваш код инициализации вью-элементов в него.

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    initViews();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Все `view`-элементы имеющие `id` восстанавливаются систематически ,но если вы создали элемент путем программного кода ,то тогда вам надо поместить значение этого элелемента в Sp потом при надобности их от-тудаже и достать ,вот краткий мануал об этом прошу 
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php

Comment: Вью сохранить в преференсы?

Comment: Ты не view сохраняещь а её значение и при возвате извкаешь

Comment: Аааааааа понял .

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите в манифесте к вашему `Activity`:

`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"`